# Stop ember from concatenating model name to adapter's namespace

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an API that expects a GET request at this URI:

```
/rooms/500
```

which will return all of the conference rooms that hold 500 people.  The number could differ as it is entered by the user.

I am using Ember.js and my adapter looks like this, hardcoded for testing:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   namespace: 'rooms/500',
});
```

But the model name (`rooms`) always gets concatenated to the request, making it `/rooms/500/rooms`, for which there is no endpoint.  How can I get Ember to stop changing the `namespace`?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the meaning of 500? It's static or changable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`namespace` has another purpose. It used as a prefix for all your request with this adapter. You can read in details [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_path-customization).

By convention, number after resource name used as resource id. In your case:

- `rooms` - resource name
- `500` - resource id

So to get what you need you can use next code in your controller/route:

```
store.findRecord('room', 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, you helped me find a solution.  I left the adapter untouched, and changed the route model() hook to use this.store.query('rooms', filter: { size: 500 } ...

Comment: Yeah.. Glad to help!